# How to crop image on selecting certain area of it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, crop

I would like to crop image by selecting some area of it by dragging it over image.

Comment: Umm..ok? we can't help you if theres no question, or you atleast have *attempted* something. we aren't code monkeys nor mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, its a jquery plugin http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler which help u get the coordinates for the crop region. when you get those coordinates you can use the 
following function in c#.

```
   Rectangle CropArea; // assign the rectangle the x,y cordinates.   
   Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
   Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
   bmpImage.PixelFormat);
   return (Image)(bmpCrop);
```